# ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME in android

Tags: android, ionic-framework, webview, inappbrowser

**I am trying to open google-forms link using InAppBrowser webview. My code is :**

```
  private _launchInAppBrowser(link : string) : void {
let opts : string = "location=yes,clearcache=yes,hidespinner=no,usewkwebview=true"
let iab = this._browser.create(link, '_blank', opts);
iab.show();
```

}

Above works fine in ios device, but for android device it gives UNKNOWN URL issue

Note: When i provide the complete url, it works fine in Android also.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you might have a missing access origin setting in your config.xml file.

Add this property in ur config.xml. After adding you will have to remove platform android and add it back again.

`<access origin="*" />`

Adding this allows every origin- then later you can restrict after that if required.

Comment: <access origin="*" subdomains="true" />
    <access origin="cdvfile://*" />
<access launch-external="true" origin="mailto:*" />

Anything else needs to be changed?